# Jquery select checkboxes inside a div element

Tags: jquery

I have a checkbox inside a div element . I would like to mark the checkbox as checked whenevever i click the button .. The div element tag is as follows

```
<div class ="test123" style ="width:90px;">
<input id = "chk1" type = "checkbox" value="on"/>
</div>
```

I am doing something like this , but its not working for me

```
$(".test123 ").find("input:checked").each(function() {
    //code to check the checkbox
});​
```

Please suggest..

Nav.

Answer (score 2):

```
$('#btn').click(function(){

    $('.test123').find('input[type=checkbox]').attr('checked','true');



    });
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$('.btn').click(function(){
 $('#chk1').attr('checked','checked'); // $('#chk1').attr("checked","true");
})
```

both should work fine for you.

HTML

```
<div class ="test123" style ="width:90px;">
<input id = "chk1" type = "checkbox" value="on"/>
</div>
<input type="button" class="btn" />
```

Comment: but that would mean , i need to click on the div, right ? what i would like to have is , to click the button and have the checkbox inside the div checked..

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by

```
$('#btn').click(function(){
 $('#chk1').attr("checked","true");
})

<input type="button" id="btn" />
```

Comment: but that would mean , i need to click on the div, right ? what i would like to have is , to click the button and have the checkbox inside the div checked..

Answer (score 0):

```
$(".test123 ").find("input:checked").each(function() {
```

Instead of the above one.. try using

```
    $("#button").click(function() {
        $(".test123").find("input:checkbox").each(function() {
            if($(this).attr('checked')) {
            } else {
                $(this).attr('checked','checked');
            }
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

the best way for your solution is use a label instead a div like this

```
<label class ="test123" style ="width:90px;">
    <input id="chk1" type="checkbox" value="on"/>
</label>
```

so you will not need a javascript code!